# How to add a scrollbar to an element using react-bulma-components?

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I'm learning *React* with *Bulma* and I want to add a table with a fixed size, so that if some of the table elements don't have enough space to render, a scrollbar appears.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to wrap the element inside a `<Box>` setting up the height and overflowY like this:

```
<Box style={{ height:"50%", overflowY:"auto" }}>
<Table>
.
.
.
</Table>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bulma specifies on their docs that if you want a table to be scrollable you could use the class table-container. I was looking for a table container on react-bulma-components and they don't provide one but you can make one if you want with something like

```
const TableContainer = (props) => {
   const width = props.width ? props.width : '100%'
   const height = props.height ? props.height : '100%'  

   return (
    <div style={width, height, overflow: 'auto'}>
       {props.children}
    </div>
   )
}
```